# Creating rows of Midnight to Midnight datespans for multiple rows in a timerange

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following problem and I am wondering how best to resolve it in SQL.
I have a table like follows:

[image]

And I would like to create spans like the following in another table:

```
2019-06-24 19:15:05 -> 2019-06-24 23:59:00
2019-06-25 00:00:00 -> 2019-06-26 18:47:39
2019-06-26 19:02:40 -> 2019-06-26 23:59:00 
2019-06-27 00:00:00 -> 2019-06-27 23:59:00 
2019-06-28 00:00:00 -> 2019-06-28 23:59:00 
2019-06-29 00:00:00 -> 2019-06-29 23:59:00 
2019-06-30 00:00:00 -> 2019-06-30 23:59:00
2019-07-01 00:00:00 -> 2019-07-01 23:59:00 
2019-07-02 00:00:00 -> 2019-07-02 01:58:32
2019-07-02 02:01:10 -> 2019-07-02 23:59:00 
2019-07-03 00:00:00 -> 2019-07-03 23:59:00
2019-07-04 00:00:00 -> 2019-07-04 23:59:00
2019-07-05 00:00:00 -> 2019-07-05 01:35:00
```

So essentially my spans need to go from the FromTimes to the ToTimes with a new row for each midnight in between for each day

Can anybody let me know the best approach for this? I have tried a cursor iterating over every day within the spans, but I don't think this is the best approach. Can anybody give some guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite see why you would stop at a minute before midnight.  I would get the complete days using a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select fromtime,
             (case when datediff(day, fromtime, totime) = 0
                   then totime
                   else dateadd(day, 1, convert(date, fromtime))
              end) as dayendtime,
             totime
      from t
      union all
      select dayendtime as fromtime,
             (case when datediff(day, dayendtime, totime) = 0
                   then totime
                   else dateadd(day, 1, dayendtime)
              end) as dayendtime,
             totime
       from cte
       where dayendtime < totime
      )
select fromtime, dateadd(minute, -1, dayendtime)
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b7bdda46eb909f8b7be778de10b78587) is a db<>fiddle.

If you can have more than 100 days, then you need to add `option (maxrecursion 0)` to the query.

Comment: If this is something that you use often, I would consider creating a calendar table with the time ranges and joining those to your table instead of creating them 'on the fly'.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for the help! This query isn't returning the desired resultset for me, also, shouldn't I have a stop condition for this recursion? Thanks

Comment: @user1501171 . . . I fixed some small problems and added a db<>fiddle.